# sketch pluginでPin to EdgeとFix Sizeの値を取得したい。

Tags: javascript

現在、私は既存の[プラグイン](https://developer.sketch.com/reference/api/)と[こちら](https://medium.com/zendesk-engineering/reverse-engineering-sketchs-resizing-functionality-23f6aae2da1a)のページを参考に自作でプラグインの開発を行っています。
描画させたいのはiPoneでもAndroidでもない為、画面の要素一つ一つの座標を取得したいと思っております。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

## Pin to EdgeとFix Sizeの値

symbolに存在するPin to EdgeとFix Sizeの値を取得できる変数が分かりません。

きっと[2つ目のリンク](https://medium.com/zendesk-engineering/reverse-engineering-sketchs-resizing-functionality-23f6aae2da1a)に貼っている、「resizesContent」と「resizingConstraint」の変数を取得すれば良いと思うのですが、２つの変数の取得方法が[１つ目のリンク](https://developer.sketch.com/reference/api/)に記載がないのか変数名が違うのかどう取得すればいいのか分かりません。

この値が取得できない為、画面の要素一つ一つの座標を取得してもズレが発生してしまいます。
知っている方がいらっしゃいましたら教えて頂けると幸いです。

Comment: 「上記のサイトを参考に」の情報が抜け落ちているようなので、差支えなければURL等を含めてもらうといいかもしれません。質問は後からでも [編集] できるので、必要に応じて追記してみてください。

Comment: リンクを貼り忘れておりました。